Can i login using only pin in Auth::attempt
i tried this to login but it failed to login in system
if (Auth::attempt(['mpin' => $otp])) {
    $check_otp->update(['otp' => '']);

    session()->put('is_login', true);
    session()->flash('success', 'Logged In Successfully');

    $this->redirectRoute('dashboard', navigate: true);
} else {
    $this->dispatch(
        'alert',
        type: 'error',
        message: 'You have entered invalid OTP'
    );

    return;
}


is username and password mandatory to pass inside auth::attempt () method?

Show your entire code with method.What error you are getting ? What is $check_otp?Please clarify all this. And also share your route defination.

Whether Auth::attempt(['mpin' => $otp]) works depends on what Auth Provider you use.
By default, Laravel uses the EloquentUserProvider which requires password to be passed in the array. To be more specific, it uses the retrieveByCredentials method and validateCredentials method to validate the credentials
I can't remember there being any Providers in-built that supports skipping the password field since Laravel is designed to work with username/email and a password
If you need Auth::attempt() to work without the password key, you would need to implement your own UserProvider

is username and password mandatory to pass inside auth::attempt () method?

So to answer your question, password is mandatory. You may pass any other field along with it such as email or username, any field you like and Laravel will query the database using this field.
For example, if you do Auth::attempt(['hello'=>'world', 'foo' => 'bar', 'password' => 'foobar']), Laravel will do a User::where('hello', 'world')->where('foo', 'bar')->first() query and check if the password matches foobar
